# Not finding all graphics in graphicspath

Tags: graphics, pdftex

I am able to build fine in Windows, but when I move to my Ubuntu machine and attempt to build from there, it looks like pdflatex is finding some pictures in my graphicspath but not others. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks! I've included the log, and bolded two instances: the first one, it finds the graphic in the path, the second, for some reason it doesn't. Both images exist, and are named correctly.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2014.5.19)  3 JUN 2014 18:52
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**SciTechDraft3.tex
(./SciTechDraft3.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/aiaa/aiaa-tc.cls
Document Class: aiaa-tc 2004/04/03 v3.5 AIAA technical conference paper
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count87
\Gm@cntv=\count88
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count89
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen103
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen104
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen105
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen106
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen107
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen108
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen109
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen110
\Gm@dimlist=\toks15
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count90
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen111
\Gin@req@width=\dimen112
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
Package: array 2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen113
\extrarowheight=\dimen114
\NC@list=\toks16
\extratabsurround=\skip43
\backup@length=\skip44
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cite/overcite.sty
Package: overcite 1999/04/23  v 3.8
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lastpage/lastpage.sty
Package: lastpage 2013/01/28 v1.2l Refers to last page's name (HMM; JPG)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty
\fancy@headwidth=\skip45
\f@ncyO@elh=\skip46
\f@ncyO@erh=\skip47
\f@ncyO@olh=\skip48
\f@ncyO@orh=\skip49
\f@ncyO@elf=\skip50
\f@ncyO@erf=\skip51
\f@ncyO@olf=\skip52
\f@ncyO@orf=\skip53
)
\c@aiaa@cthanks=\count91
\c@aiaa@cfootnote=\count92
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks17
\inpenc@posthook=\toks18

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
File: utf8.def 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
Now handling font encoding OML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
Now handling font encoding T1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T1

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu
File: t1enc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
   defining Unicode char U+00AB (decimal 171)
   defining Unicode char U+00BB (decimal 187)
   defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
   defining Unicode char U+00C0 (decimal 192)
   defining Unicode char U+00C1 (decimal 193)
   defining Unicode char U+00C2 (decimal 194)
   defining Unicode char U+00C3 (decimal 195)
   defining Unicode char U+00C4 (decimal 196)
   defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
   defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
   defining Unicode char U+00C7 (decimal 199)
   defining Unicode char U+00C8 (decimal 200)
   defining Unicode char U+00C9 (decimal 201)
   defining Unicode char U+00CA (decimal 202)
   defining Unicode char U+00CB (decimal 203)
   defining Unicode char U+00CC (decimal 204)
   defining Unicode char U+00CD (decimal 205)
   defining Unicode char U+00CE (decimal 206)
   defining Unicode char U+00CF (decimal 207)
   defining Unicode char U+00D0 (decimal 208)
   defining Unicode char U+00D1 (decimal 209)
   defining Unicode char U+00D2 (decimal 210)
   defining Unicode char U+00D3 (decimal 211)
   defining Unicode char U+00D4 (decimal 212)
   defining Unicode char U+00D5 (decimal 213)
   defining Unicode char U+00D6 (decimal 214)
   defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
   defining Unicode char U+00D9 (decimal 217)
   defining Unicode char U+00DA (decimal 218)
   defining Unicode char U+00DB (decimal 219)
   defining Unicode char U+00DC (decimal 220)
   defining Unicode char U+00DD (decimal 221)
   defining Unicode char U+00DE (decimal 222)
   defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
   defining Unicode char U+00E0 (decimal 224)
   defining Unicode char U+00E1 (decimal 225)
   defining Unicode char U+00E2 (decimal 226)
   defining Unicode char U+00E3 (decimal 227)
   defining Unicode char U+00E4 (decimal 228)
   defining Unicode char U+00E5 (decimal 229)
   defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
   defining Unicode char U+00E7 (decimal 231)
   defining Unicode char U+00E8 (decimal 232)
   defining Unicode char U+00E9 (decimal 233)
   defining Unicode char U+00EA (decimal 234)
   defining Unicode char U+00EB (decimal 235)
   defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
   defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
   defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
   defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
   defining Unicode char U+00F0 (decimal 240)
   defining Unicode char U+00F1 (decimal 241)
   defining Unicode char U+00F2 (decimal 242)
   defining Unicode char U+00F3 (decimal 243)
   defining Unicode char U+00F4 (decimal 244)
   defining Unicode char U+00F5 (decimal 245)
   defining Unicode char U+00F6 (decimal 246)
   defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
   defining Unicode char U+00F9 (decimal 249)
   defining Unicode char U+00FA (decimal 250)
   defining Unicode char U+00FB (decimal 251)
   defining Unicode char U+00FC (decimal 252)
   defining Unicode char U+00FD (decimal 253)
   defining Unicode char U+00FE (decimal 254)
   defining Unicode char U+00FF (decimal 255)
   defining Unicode char U+0102 (decimal 258)
   defining Unicode char U+0103 (decimal 259)
   defining Unicode char U+0104 (decimal 260)
   defining Unicode char U+0105 (decimal 261)
   defining Unicode char U+0106 (decimal 262)
   defining Unicode char U+0107 (decimal 263)
   defining Unicode char U+010C (decimal 268)
   defining Unicode char U+010D (decimal 269)
   defining Unicode char U+010E (decimal 270)
   defining Unicode char U+010F (decimal 271)
   defining Unicode char U+0110 (decimal 272)
   defining Unicode char U+0111 (decimal 273)
   defining Unicode char U+0118 (decimal 280)
   defining Unicode char U+0119 (decimal 281)
   defining Unicode char U+011A (decimal 282)
   defining Unicode char U+011B (decimal 283)
   defining Unicode char U+011E (decimal 286)
   defining Unicode char U+011F (decimal 287)
   defining Unicode char U+0130 (decimal 304)
   defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
   defining Unicode char U+0132 (decimal 306)
   defining Unicode char U+0133 (decimal 307)
   defining Unicode char U+0139 (decimal 313)
   defining Unicode char U+013A (decimal 314)
   defining Unicode char U+013D (decimal 317)
   defining Unicode char U+013E (decimal 318)
   defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
   defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
   defining Unicode char U+0143 (decimal 323)
   defining Unicode char U+0144 (decimal 324)
   defining Unicode char U+0147 (decimal 327)
   defining Unicode char U+0148 (decimal 328)
   defining Unicode char U+014A (decimal 330)
   defining Unicode char U+014B (decimal 331)
   defining Unicode char U+0150 (decimal 336)
   defining Unicode char U+0151 (decimal 337)
   defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
   defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
   defining Unicode char U+0154 (decimal 340)
   defining Unicode char U+0155 (decimal 341)
   defining Unicode char U+0158 (decimal 344)
   defining Unicode char U+0159 (decimal 345)
   defining Unicode char U+015A (decimal 346)
   defining Unicode char U+015B (decimal 347)
   defining Unicode char U+015E (decimal 350)
   defining Unicode char U+015F (decimal 351)
   defining Unicode char U+0160 (decimal 352)
   defining Unicode char U+0161 (decimal 353)
   defining Unicode char U+0162 (decimal 354)
   defining Unicode char U+0163 (decimal 355)
   defining Unicode char U+0164 (decimal 356)
   defining Unicode char U+0165 (decimal 357)
   defining Unicode char U+016E (decimal 366)
   defining Unicode char U+016F (decimal 367)
   defining Unicode char U+0170 (decimal 368)
   defining Unicode char U+0171 (decimal 369)
   defining Unicode char U+0178 (decimal 376)
   defining Unicode char U+0179 (decimal 377)
   defining Unicode char U+017A (decimal 378)
   defining Unicode char U+017B (decimal 379)
   defining Unicode char U+017C (decimal 380)
   defining Unicode char U+017D (decimal 381)
   defining Unicode char U+017E (decimal 382)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
   defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
   defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
   defining Unicode char U+201A (decimal 8218)
   defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
   defining Unicode char U+201E (decimal 8222)
   defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)
   defining Unicode char U+2031 (decimal 8241)
   defining Unicode char U+2039 (decimal 8249)
   defining Unicode char U+203A (decimal 8250)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
)
Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OT1

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu
File: ot1enc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
   defining Unicode char U+00B8 (decimal 184)
   defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
   defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
   defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
   defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
   defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
   defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
   defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
   defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
   defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
   defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
   defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
   defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
   defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
   defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
   defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
   defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
   defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
   defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
   defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
   defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu
File: omsenc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
   defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
   defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
   defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
   defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
   defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
)
Now handling font encoding OMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
   defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
   defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
   defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
   defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
   defining Unicode char U+02C6 (decimal 710)
   defining Unicode char U+02DC (decimal 732)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2026 (decimal 8230)
   defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty
\wrapoverhang=\dimen115
\WF@size=\dimen116
\c@WF@wrappedlines=\count93
\WF@box=\box26
\WF@everypar=\toks19
Package: wrapfig 2003/01/31  v 3.6
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
) (./SciTechDraft3.aux)
\openout1 = `SciTechDraft3.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14.

*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: <default>
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(72.26999pt, 469.75502pt, 72.26999pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(54.2025pt, 668.4975pt, 72.26999pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=469.75502pt
* \textheight=668.4975pt
* \oddsidemargin=0.0pt
* \evensidemargin=0.0pt
* \topmargin=-55.06749pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=10.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=65.0pt
* \marginparsep=11.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count94
\scratchdimen=\dimen117
\scratchbox=\box27
\nofMPsegments=\count95
\nofMParguments=\count96
\everyMPshowfont=\toks20
\MPscratchCnt=\count97
\MPscratchDim=\dimen118
\MPnumerator=\count98
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count99
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks21
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 452.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
Package lastpage Info: Please have a look at the pageslts package at
(lastpage)             http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/ 
(lastpage)             macros/latex/contrib/pageslts/ 
(lastpage)             or
(lastpage)             http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/ 
(lastpage)             install/macros/latex/contrib/pageslts.tds.zip
(lastpage)             ! on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 29.

**<./Pics/team2.png, id=1, 1397.22pt x 698.61pt>
File: ./Pics/team2.png Graphic file (type png)
 <use ./Pics/team2.png>**
Package pdftex.def Info: ./Pics/team2.png used on input line 52.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 352.31024pt x 176.15512pt.


LaTeX Warning: `!h' float specifier changed to `!ht'.

[1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 61.


**LaTeX Warning: File `scheduleFig.png' not found on input line 65.**


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `scheduleFig.png' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.65        \includegraphics[scale=1]{scheduleFig.png}

Using draft setting for this image.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

[2 <./Pics/team2.png>] [3] [4]

LaTeX Warning: File `workflow.png' not found on input line 112.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `workflow.png' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.112       \includegraphics[scale=1]{workflow.png}

Using draft setting for this image.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


LaTeX Warning: `!h' float specifier changed to `!ht'.

<./Pics/missionProfile.png, id=31, 704.8734pt x 348.3414pt>
File: ./Pics/missionProfile.png Graphic file (type png)

<use ./Pics/missionProfile.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: ./Pics/missionProfile.png used on input line 125.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 704.87169pt x 348.34055pt.


LaTeX Warning: `!h' float specifier changed to `!ht'.

[5]
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+cmr on input line 139.

 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd
File: omscmr.fd 1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OMS/cmr/m/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' tried instead on input line 139.

<./Pics/sampleOutput.png, id=35, 2102.85625pt x 1742.51pt>
File: ./Pics/sampleOutput.png Graphic file (type png)

<use ./Pics/sampleOutput.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: ./Pics/sampleOutput.png used on input line 148.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 2102.85114pt x 1742.50577pt.


LaTeX Warning: `!h' float specifier changed to `!ht'.

[6]

LaTeX Warning: File `optimusWorkflow.png' not found on input line 165.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `optimusWorkflow.png' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.165 ...udegraphics[scale=1]{optimusWorkflow.png}

Using draft setting for this image.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


LaTeX Warning: `!h' float specifier changed to `!ht'.

[7 <./Pics/missionProfile.png>] [8 <./Pics/sampleOutput.png>] [9]

LaTeX Warning: File `cloud.png' not found on input line 186.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `cloud.png' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.186       \includegraphics[scale=1]{cloud.png}

Using draft setting for this image.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

[10] <./Pics/validate.png, id=55, 1396.21625pt x 1141.26375pt>
File: ./Pics/validate.png Graphic file (type png)

<use ./Pics/validate.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: ./Pics/validate.png used on input line 203.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 469.7433pt x 383.96703pt.


LaTeX Warning: `!h' float specifier changed to `!ht'.

[11] (./SciTechDraft3.bbl [12 <./Pics/validate.png>])

AED: lastpage setting LastPage
[13] (./SciTechDraft3.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2707 strings out of 495028
 37099 string characters out of 6181497
 105974 words of memory out of 5000000
 5853 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 9547 words of font info for 34 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 38i,11n,45p,1396b,366s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/a
msfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfont
s/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/c
mbx8.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx9.pf
b></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb></us
r/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi8.pfb></usr/share
/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texliv
e/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf
-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr6.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fo
nts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type
1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public
/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfo
nts/cm/cmsy6.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
cmsy8.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.
pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti8.pfb></u
sr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt10.pfb></usr/sha
re/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt8.pfb>
Output written on SciTechDraft3.pdf (13 pages, 1819514 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 128 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 86 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 21 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: File systems under Linux are usually case sensitive in contrary to Windows. Check carefully the file names. What's your setting of `\graphicspath`? Where are the missing files located?

Comment: It would be more helpful to see your code and the log for a minimal example. For example, one which loads just one of the found images and one of the unfound images. I notice that all of those not found are located in your current working directory, whereas those which are found are located in a sub-directory.

Comment: also unrelated to figures not being found, don't use `\begin{figure}[!h]` it just generated `LaTeX Warning: '!h' float specifier changed to '!ht'.`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for mentioning the case sensitivity. All of the ones that weren't being found had "PNG" file extensions whereas I was calling them all with "png" extensions. I read somewhere that I can just call the filename without an extension as well, so I think that's really the solution to a problem like this. Now I'm having a Bibtex issue, but that's unrelated. Pressing on!